# How to root Nexus 6P w/ unofficial LineageOS 17.1?

Tags: rooting, twrp, nexus-6p, magisk, supersu

I flashed [PixelBoot's unofficial LineageOS 17.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/orig-development/rom-lineageos-17-0-nexus-6p-angler-t4012099) on Nexus 6P, however I failed to root it.

First I tried flashing Magisk-v20.4.zip, which failed w/ "cannot mount /vendor" error. [Here](https://www.didgeridoohan.com/magisk/Magisk#:%7E:text=If%20you%20get%20this%20message,compatible%20TWRP%20for%20your%20device.) suggests I should upgrade TWRP to a "Treble compatible version" but my TWRP is already the latest 3.3.1-0.

Secondly I installed MagiskManager-v7.5.1.apk to see if I could use the "patch boot.img" approach. But it kept "checking for updates" till the end of the world, not showing the "install" button at all. I [should probably opt out of the canary channel](https://www.didgeridoohan.com/magisk/ManagerIssues#:%7E:text=If%20the%20Manager%20is%20constantly,channel%20json%20file%20has%20changed.), however I am already in the stable channel.

Thirdly I looked for LineageOS's su addon zip. Unfortunately they offer that kinda thing [for 16.0, 15.1 and 14.1 only](https://download.lineageos.org/extras).

As the last resort I flashed SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip and installed supersu-2-82.apk. But the latter just fails to detect the former and refuses to work.

How am I supposed to root my phone?

It it because of [the incompatibility between Android10(LOS17.1) and TWRP](https://twrp.me/site/update/2019/10/23/twrp-and-android-10.html)?

Comment: Darn it. Anti-DDoS issue. [solution](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/2905#issuecomment-647087771)